# How to loop through R script containing a Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app at the start of my script. After a button press ("Los gehts") the script which is taking data from clipboard is processed. Currently, I need to run the script, the shiny App opens, I fill in the data and on button click, the script runs. For the next ID I have to start the skript again.

I want it to change so that:

- I only have to start the script once, the shiny app opens and waits for input
- on click on "Los gehts" the part processing the data runs and loops, so that the shiny app opens again after processing the data
- this goes on until I klick "abbrechen" (cancel)

I tried wrapping everything fstarting from "shinyApp(ui, server)" till the end in a while loop. This, however prevents the shiny UI from loading and the data processing part just loops by itself.

So: how to loop through the script, so that the shiny UI loads at each loops and waits for the user?

```
library(shiny)

# Define global variables
if (!exists("ADI_ID")) {
  ADI_ID <- ""
}
if (!exists("timepoint")) {
  timepoint <- ""
}
if (!exists("counter")) {
  counter <- 1
}

stop <- FALSE

  ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput('adi_id', 'Enter ADI ID:'),
    textInput('timepoint', 'Enter Timepoint:', value = ""),
    actionButton('start_button', 'Los gehts'),
    actionButton('last_id_button', 'Letzter Proband'),  # Updated button label
    actionButton('cancel_button', 'Abbrechen'),
    textOutput('last_id_output'),
    textOutput('counter_output')  # New text output for displaying the counter
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$start_button, {
      if (input$adi_id == "" || input$timepoint == "") {
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            title = "Error",
            "Please enter a valid ADI ID and timepoint before proceeding.",
            easyClose = TRUE
          )
        )
      } else {
        if (ADI_ID == input$adi_id) {
          counter <<- counter + 1  # Increase counter by 1
        } else {
          counter <<- 1  # Set counter to 0
        }
        
        ADI_ID <<- input$adi_id
        timepoint <<- input$timepoint
        stopApp()
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$last_id_button, {
      if (counter >= 4) {
        showModal(
          modalDialog(
            title = "Warning",
            "Counter is 3 or higher. Are you sure you want to use the last ID?",
            footer = tagList(
              modalButton("Cancel"),
              actionButton("confirm_last_id", "Continue")
            ),
            easyClose = TRUE
          )
        )
      } else {
        updateTextInput(session, 'adi_id', value = ADI_ID)
        updateTextInput(session, 'timepoint', value = timepoint)  # Update timepoint input
      }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$confirm_last_id, {
      updateTextInput(session, 'adi_id', value = ADI_ID)
      updateTextInput(session, 'timepoint', value = timepoint)  # Update timepoint input
      removeModal()
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$cancel_button, {
      stop <<- TRUE
      stopApp()
    })
    
    observe({
      if (stop) {
        stopApp()
      }
    })
    
    output$last_id_output <- renderText({
      paste("Last ID: ", ADI_ID)
    })
    
    output$counter_output <- renderText({
      paste("Counter: ", counter)
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)


  if (stop == TRUE) {
    stop("Abgebrochen")
  } else { 
my_data <- read_clip()
####### Rest of my script processing the data
```

Comment: Why not move the processing inside the shiny app, to be initiated by your button click?  Then you need only load the shiny app.  No need to loop.  I can't show you how to do that because your code sample is incomplete...

Comment: wow, how didn't I think of that!? (I added the Shiny App later, so I just put it before the existing code). BUt basically, I can take the whole code and put it inside the server function, right?

Comment: That's what I would do.

Comment: Worked perfectly!